# Changing domain in numerical method for ln(x)

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation

Say for instance I have found a method for numerically calculating $ln(x)$ for values of $x$ between $\frac 12$ and $\frac 32$. How would I extend the method I already have so that the method works for all $x>0$? I imagine I'd have to use the logarithmic laws to manipulate $ln(x)$ somehow, but I honestly don't know where to go from here.

Comment: ln(ab)= ln(a)+ ln(b). So for example ln(1/2*2)=ln(2)+ln(1/2). So you can find ln(2) from that. in general this is just a preliminary ln(1/a*a)=ln(a) + ln(1/a). So for 2/3a<a<2 you can find ln(a).

Comment: @Sorfosh Ok, but that method only goes so far. You can't use that method to find values of x any larger 3.

Comment: then use the new values to generate more.

Comment: @Sorfosh That's not at all practical. Calculating the natural log of stupendously large numbers would take days to do. I'm looking for a way to find the natural log of a number greater than 0 in only one calculation.

Comment: if you can find a way to get all values of ln(x) for 0<x<1, you can easily find all the other values by using $ln(n)=-ln(1/n)$.

Comment: @Sorfosh Did you read what I've written? I want to find a method that works in one step. And even if I was to go about doing it that way, there would be no way to find the natural log of some infinitely small decimal. I just can't see how to do it with the knowledge and resources I have.